# Manually track screens with firebase not working in swift

Tags: swift, firebase-analytics

I am trying to track screen with my manual screen name to firebase analytics as Documentation says.

```
Analytics.setScreenName("MyScreenName", screenClass: nil)
```

Still my screen name in firebase analytics only showing not set.
And I added `-FIRDEBUGENABLED` and
`-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` to debug tracking screen name. 
Still I cant see any debug message of tracking my screen name. 
Is there anything wrong or anything to debug manually tracking screen in iOS swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. All I have to solve is putting that tracking screen code inside `ViewDidAppear` and now the manual tracking screen works perfectly.